# If Cinderella's shoe fit perfectly, why did it fall off?

Tags: cinderella-1950

In Disney's *Cinderella* (1950), what was the reason for Cinderella's shoe to fall off? After all, we all know that the shoe she wears fits her perfectly.

Comment: @uhoh the slipper falling off as Cinderella runs from the ball at midnight is a fairly common plot anchor in most movie adaptations

Comment: She loses her shoe because that's what the story requires. Also, there is a pattern: https://www.popsugar.co.uk/love/photo-gallery/43613656/image/43613636/Cinderella-loses-her-shoe-3-different-times-throughout-film

Comment: Possible (but non-canonical) answers: https://www.theguardian.com/theguardian/2013/jan/09/why-cinderella-lost-her-slipper

Comment: I'm not clear why the tag Disney was removed. That narrows it down to one of two heavily connected properties, the 1950 cartoon film or its live-action remake.

Comment: @Valorum I've added "Disney's Cinderella (1950)" to the question body to clarify the movie being discussed. I've removed [disney] since it is being used as a meta tag in this case. As per the tag usage guidance, [disney] is only for questions about the company and is not to be used for questions about specific Disney movies.

Comment: @galacticninja - But is it the cartoon they're asking about, or the live action film? Disney made both...

Comment: @Valorum The [[tag:cinderella]] tag is about the 1950 animated film (as per its tag wiki), and the OP chose that tag when they initially posted their question.

Comment: @galacticninja - Yes, but they also chose the wrong tag when they picked [Disney]. Your argument seems to be that they carefully selected one tag correctly (which we should respect) and one tag incorrectly (which we should ignore)

Comment: @Valorum In this question, [disney] was used incorrectly as a meta tag. This is not a question about Disney as a company or Disney's works in general. In any case, the film that the question is about is already named in the question body, so the [disney] tag is redundant.

Comment: @Valorum The [disney] tag just isn't to be used on questions that are simply about Disney movies unrelated to the intricacies of Disney as the production company. If that makes the question confusing, that is a different problem but not to be solved by invalid supplementary tags. Rather the actual tags need more refinement then, but this has been mitigated by extending the tag usage guidance (it could be further mitigated by adding a `1950` to the existing tag. But in any case, the usage of [disney] here is invalid an orthogonal to any other tagging problems).

Answer (score 6):

Slippers are supposed to be relatively easy to slip on and off, even if they are a close fit.

Also, a glass slipper wouldn't be breathable, and dancing in a warm ballroom would result in fairly sweaty feet, which would facilitate it slipping off.